# TFS Interface with remote Git repository

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I have searched, but could not find the answer. If I missed it, please point me that way.

Is it possible to use the TFS UI in Visual Studio 2013 to connect to a remote Git repository, and if so, can you point me in the right direction? If it is not possible, is there a fully integrated UI available somewhere for Git that works as well as the integrated TFS interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS supports both: Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) and Git. This diagram gives an overview.

[image]
[Image source](https://mohammedumar.wordpress.com/).

When you create a new project in TFS, you can choose whether you want to use TFVC for source code version control or whether you want to use Git.

[image]

For more information, see [Getting Started with Git in Visual Studio and Team Foundation Service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/01/30/getting-started-with-git-in-visual-studio-and-team-foundation-service.aspx). This blog post talks about the online hosting service which used to be called *Team Foundation Service*, but was later rebranded to *[Visual Studio Online](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/what-is-visual-studio-online-vs.aspx)*. I'm assuming that a TFS server installed on-premise works similarly.

Visual Studio 2013 supports both TFVC and Git out of the box: [Use Visual Studio with Git](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850437.aspx). The Git-UI in Visual Studio used to be pretty bad: it just supported few Git commands and the UI design was confusing. Now, I find it sort of ok. It's getting better with each release, though.

Comment: I should have given more context.  My team is moving away from SVN.  Part of the team is wanting to use a remote GIT repository, and I have been pushing for TFS because I really like the interface.  I had read that you could use TFS with a remote GIT back end, but I am having trouble finding information on how to do that.  The above does answer the second part of the question.

Comment: @user3179754: I updated the answer with the new context. How about now? Is that what you were looking for?